# Vlookup on range upto last row available from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to `vlookup` data from the workbook `Daily_Report BOE.xlsx` to workbook `Sales wk02.xlsx`.

Thing is, the number of rows in `Daily_Report BOE.xlsx` could change.
So looking this information up with specific row number would not work. Could you help?

**My code:**

```
Windows("Sales wk02.xlsx").Activate
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[Daily_Report BOE.xlsx]Nocturne'!R4C1:R105C13,13,0)"
```

Is there anyway I could select up to the last row with data available ?

Comment: Is it possible to format the results on `Daily_Report BOE` as a table? If so, your range reference would go from `'[Daily_Report BOE.xlsx]Nocturne'!R4C1:R105C13'` to `'[Daily_Report BOE.xlsx]TableName`. No adjustment needed when the workbook size changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Workbooks("Daily_Report BOE.xlsx").Sheets("Nocturne").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

' ~~~ change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name where you want to add this formula ~~~
Workbooks("Sales wk02.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[Daily_Report BOE.xlsx]Nocturne'!R4C1:R" & LastRow & " C13,13,0)"
```

**Note**: there's no need to use `Activate`, `Select` and `ActiveCell`, you can use fully qalified `Range` instead.